# Play a random sound

Tags: objective-c, ios, random, audio

How can i play a random sound in iOS 5 in xcode? 
I keep getting a "throwing an exception" error.

I tried this:

```
int randomNumber = arc4random() % 24 + 1;

NSString *tmpFileNameRandom = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Sound%d", randomNumber];

NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tmpFileNameRandom ofType:@"mp3"];

AVAudioPlayer * soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName] error:nil];

[soundPlayer prepareToPlay];
[soundPlayer play];
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried logging the file paths/names, are these correct etc also what exception is being thrown and by what.

Comment: %d should be fine - they're equivalent (%d is not "double", in case you're wondering).

Comment: Do you get an exception every time or only occasionally? Are your sound files named Sound1.mp3 to Sound24.mp3?

Comment: Give us a clue at least..... hows about posting the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: what's not working? Silence? Crash? Daemons out of your nose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change your ViewController.h to

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AVAudioPlayer;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)PlayRandomSound;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *soundPlayer;


@end
```

and first lines of ViewController.m to

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>


@implementation ViewController

@synthesize soundPlayer = _soundPlayer;


-(IBAction)PlayRandomSound{

    int randomNumber = arc4random() % 8 + 1;

    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sound%02d", randomNumber] ofType:@"mp3"]];


    _soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];

    [_soundPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_soundPlayer play];


    NSLog(@"randomNumber is %d", randomNumber);
    NSLog(@"tmpFilename is %@", soundURL);
}
```

Edit: i only later noticed that you don't use ARC so this code has a small leak. But it will do for start. Maybe you should set _soundPlayer to nil when you create ViewController and later check: if it's not nil: release it and create new one, otherwise just create new one. Or you could consider switching to ARC if it's a new project.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thanks a lot. I'm a sounddesigner, if i ever can return you a soundfavour let me know!

Answer (score 1):

For your filenames you should use

```
NSString *tmpFileNameRandom = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Sound%02d", randomNumber];
```

this will give you leading zeros with numbers < 10...

or better yet, try this:

```
int randomNumber = arc4random() % 24 + 1;

NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sound%02d", randomNumber] ofType:@"mp3"]];

AVAudioPlayer * soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];

[soundPlayer prepareToPlay];
[soundPlayer play];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - you should accept it if you want people to carry on helping you.

Comment: Hi, the filenames are now confirmed right but it still doesn't play the actual sound. An NSLog of soundURL returns for instance Sound02.mp3 which is a valid file in the xcode project. I get no errors, sound of iphone is on, sound of mac is on but nothing...

Comment: Hmm, your code looks right - it should play. Make three thigs sure: That your filenames really match character by character (capital S) and that the format is correct (mp3?). Files should also be included in a project (right click on project viewer -> add files to project).

Comment: Also, don't forget to include AVFoundation.framework
into your project and import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"
to the file where you call AVAudioPlayer from.

Comment: I uploaded the testproject here, i have no clue anymore. Starting to think it might be xcode... http://wtrns.fr/SaHfHkPw1l7WHQG

Comment: Solved :) the problem is that AVAudioPlayer is released before it can play. I'll post another answer since i cant format code here in comment.

Comment: Where and how do i do that?! Is there an accept button i'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the AVFoundation framework to your project? AVAudioPlayer is a class of this framework.

To add this framework (in Xcode 4), select your project file, select the 'Summary' tab and add it by clicking on the + below the "Linked frameworks and libraries" tableview.